# Disable button until PHP execute a batch file

Tags: php, jquery

I am executing a abc.bat file using PHP exec() function when user click on anchor tag. Here is my sample code in file home.php

```
<a href="home.php?run=true">Run File</a>

if ($_GET['run'] == true) {
      $response = exec("abc.bat");
}
```

I have written some procedure call in batch file and sometime it needs 5 to 10 minutes for running. I want to disable the RUN button until the batch file executed. I think we have to use some JQuery script but I am not good enough in this. I do need your suggestion what I have to do for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a solution with jQuery, you can remove the href of your `<a>` with [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/). Moreover, you can change the style of your link to show to the user that the link is disabled (add a class "disabled" for instance).

Keep in mind, it's just UI solution.